# Execute Bash script on Ubuntu from remote Windows machine?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash

I have a bash script on a ubuntu 10.4 machine. It is shared and I can access it from my win7 machine with `\\LINUX-SERVER\bash_repo\make-live`

However when I do, windows tries to open it. This is not what I want. **I want to tell ubuntu to *execute* it.**

I am actually hoping to be able to build a GUI app on windows where the user clicks a button and it tells the bash script on the ubuntu machine to execute.

Is any of this possible?

Comment: How about installing a web server on ubuntu? You can invoke your script within a PHP/perl page.

Comment: @Khaled I do have Apache on my ubuntu machine. Why don't you elaborate a little more on how I would execute it from PHP. Thanks!!

Comment: Check the answer below.

Comment: If this is resolved please mark the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried plink from the makers of PuTTY?
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

You should be able to run the script on the ubuntu machine like:

```
plink.exe -ssh -pw pass -noagent user@linux-server /path/to/your/script/make-live
```

Comment: Wow this is wierd. The script I am trying to execute has 2 parts. part one requires sudo, part 2 echos a message. The message gets echoed but part one does not run instead I get this: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` But I think that is a different problem. So I'll still mark you correct if no other better solutions come. thanks!

Comment: @John: Try `plink -t ...` to allocate a pty.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by my comment above, you can execute your script from PHP if you have a web server running on your ubuntu machine.

A small PHP script like the following will be enough:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('bash /path/to/your/script');
echo "$output";
?>
```

Save the PHP code in a file such as `/var/www/exec.php` and point your browser from any machine to the URL `http://your_ubuntu_machine_ip/exec.php`.

Please, note that the script will be executed as `www-data` user (the default apache web server user). If you want to run a privileged command using sudo, you need to add `www-data` user to `sudoers` file using `visudo`.

You need an entry like:

```
www-data   ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/command
```

Comment: Thank you I am getting very close to what I want to do. I am having trouble with `add www-data user to sudoers` part. Can you please elaborate. visudo using vi which I have never used so I used `export EDITOR=gedit && sudo -E visudo` but that just opened an empty sudoers.tmp file. Do I add something to this file? if so what? Thank you!

Comment: -1 a php script is overly complex IMHO. plink of another commandline tool is preferable. Not to mention I'm not sure if it's even a good idea from a security point of view.

Comment: @JamesBarnett: It is not complicated! The OP already has apache installed and running. A simple PHP script will be enough to do it. It provides an easy way to execute your scripts remotely and it will not impose a security risk if it was secured in a good way. For example, you can use https instead of http if it will be invoked across an insecure network.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested you could use ssh to get a CLI session or wrap it in an accessible program, however that you can access it as a network share implies that Samba is configured and running - and there are numerous ways of getting Samba to execute files (e.g. magic script, winpopups, svcctl) [rtfm](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) for more details.